# Instagram API link not working in php file

Tags: php, json, curl, instagram, stdclass

I am trying to make a website that displays my friend's instagram follower count and recent images. I finally think I have figured out how to do it but I am running into an error. Every time I run my php file I get

> stdClass Object ( [meta] => stdClass Object ( [error_type] => APINotFoundError [code] => 400 [error_message] => invalid media id ) )

The code I am running is:

```
<?php

function extractData(){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/D?access_token=*");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
$activate= extractData();

print_r(json_decode($activate));
?>
```

I have a valid access key I just took it out for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think your endpoint URL is incorrect. It's not specifying any data, when it should look at your buddy's account.
See: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users for the return data as well.

Change the URL to match the correct user:

```
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=*");
```

Comment: Do I need to find their user-id? If so, how do I do that? @Taruckus

Comment: That's worth a separate question, but yeah, you do need the user ID. One way to get it is by using your friend's API client to authenticate (https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/). Instagram will give you their user ID when returning their associated access token. This is part of authentication: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/#important-note